# Equals Sign in Dimensional Analysis

Tags: dimensional-analysis

Is it mathematically correct to say the following:

1. 1 inch = 2.54 cm
2. 1000m  = 1 km
3. 100°C = 212°F

Here is my justification for what is true and false:

1. is in a somewhat grey area for me, it seems to be true but I think it is just because our initial statement is our definition so no real contradictions are to be made, I have no real argument to make here except that I THINK it wrong(Just intuition)

   1 = 2.54cm/1inch
2. is ABSOLUTELY true, since

   k=1000 (dimensionless)

   it is fair to say that 1000 = 1k

   if we multiply "1m" on both sides we get 1000m = 1km
3. is ABSOLUTELY false. Since division is a perfectly valid operation for non-zero numbers, dividing both sides by 100 we get,

   1°C = 2.12°F
   which is clearly wrong

A common equation is F=(9/5)C+32

I would argue here that the above equation is wrong. Even though their dimensions are the same, what differs here is the unit. Granted that this is not a maths subject we do not need to be extremely rigorous and pedantic over small details. But I am just curious.

If I were to fix the above equation I would do it as follows:

If C is the temperature in degrees celsius, then f(C) is the equivalent temperature in degrees fahrenheit

f(C) = aC + b, where

a = (9/5) °F/°C

b = 32 °F

And Here we have no contradictions. If we let C=100°C, we get the appropriate unit for f(C).

Please let me know what you think. I am just speculating here and if you could help me rectify any mistakes it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a physical meaning to the units as is done by definition, then I’d argue all three should make sense. I say so because the two things, ie the LHS and RHS of the equations are representing the same physical quantity. And by transitivity the two should be equal.

Comment: My problem with that is the contradiction I have made in 3. Another solution would be to use a different symbol rather than equals. because = means equals to NOT equivalent to.